Firebase Emulators cannot import module even when VSCode shows that the imported module has already been properly referenced
I have a Typescript project that is compiled to JS before being used to run as an emulated Firebase Functions.
My functions/lib/index.js
import ENV from './configs/dotenv';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp({
    serviceAccountId: ENV.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL
});
import { setGlobalOptions } from 'firebase-functions/v2';
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import { initializeDB } from './db';

Which was compiled with tsc && tsc-alias. This is my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]                  // Retain the alias paths for module resolution
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,            // Ensures compatibility with CommonJS modules
    "module": "ESNext",                 // Ensures TypeScript generates ES modules (for 'import' / 'export')
    "target": "ES2020",                 // Set the target ECMAScript version
    "moduleResolution": "Node",         // Ensure proper module resolution
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // Allow default imports from modules without a default export
    "outDir": "lib",                  // Output directory for compiled files
    "rootDir": "./src",                 // Root directory for your source files
    "strict": true,                       // Enable strict type checking
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],            // Include all TypeScript files in the 'src' folder
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]            // Exclude 'node_modules' from compilation
}

And this is my package.json file:
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && tsc-alias",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  },

When I run npm run serve, it says:
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ricaa\...\functions\lib\configs\dotenv' imported from C:\Users\ricaa\...\simple-tinder-like\functions\lib\index.js

Note that for the ..., I just omitted the long paths.
And in my functions/lib/configs folder, there's a dotenv.js file with this content:
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const ENV = {
    PROJECT_ID: process.env.FB_PROJECT_ID,
    FIREBASE_API_KEY: process.env.FB_API_KEY,
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL: process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY: process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY,
    DATABASE_URL: process.env.DATABASE_URL
};
const requiredEnvVars = [
    'PROJECT_ID',
    'FIREBASE_API_KEY',
    'SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL',
    'SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY',
    'DATABASE_URL'
];
requiredEnvVars.forEach((key) => {
    if (!ENV[key]) {
        throw new Error(`Missing required environment variable: ${key}`);
    }
});
export default ENV;


I'm not sure why the error still appears when I run npm run serve. Could anyone help?
